# Whats Wrong here MQTT-IONIC 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mqtt, ionic5

**Ionic 5 wiht Angular v12.1.1**

In my Ionic App in the file app.module.ts i have the MQTT Service Options, like this.

```
const MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS: IMqttServiceOptions = {

  connectOnCreate: false,

  hostname: 'localhost',

  port: 1884,

  path: '/mqtt',

  protocol: 'ws'

};
```

And then i use this options when i do the import.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
    MqttModule.forRoot(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS)
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

In my 'home.page.ts' is where i use the 'ngx-mqtt', with the purpose to listen messages for a certain topic.
The code is as follow.

```
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { error } from 'console';
import { IMqttMessage, MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS, MqttService } from 'ngx-mqtt';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private mqttService: MqttService) {
    //mqttService.connect(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS);
    /* console.log('Teste 0');
    this.subscribeToTopic();
    console.log('Teste 4'); */
  }

  ngOnInit() { }


  subscribeToTopic() {
    console.log('Teste 2');
    this.subscription = this.mqttService.observe('mqtt/demo').subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
      console.log('Mensagem:', message);
    }, (e)=> {
      console.log(e);
    });
    console.log('Teste 3');
  }

  connect() {
    console.log(this.mqttService.connect(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS));
  }

  disconnect() {
    console.log(this.mqttService.disconnect());
  }

  unSubscribe() {
    console.log(this.subscription.unsubscribe());
  }

}
```

In my home.page.html i have 4 buttons witch activate the 4 functions in the home.page.ts.

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">

  <h2>Mqtt</h2>

  <ion-button (click)="connect()">Connect</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="disconnect()">disconnect</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="subscribeToTopic()">Subscribe</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="unSubscribe()">unSubscribe</ion-button>

</ion-content>
```

---

**Mosquitto broker**

The broker is mosquitto from Eclipse **version** 2.0.14.
Is running whith custom config file like this.

websockets.conf content:

```
port 1883

listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

---

**Problem**

When i run the mosquitto broker with the custom config, and run the ionic app via 'ionic serve', this message appear in the prompt running mosquitto>.

*This appear on mosquitto prompt:*

```
Sending CONNACK to client-hu1m0vg4wxe (0, 5)

Client client-hu1m0vg4wxe closed its connection.
```

So, how i can maintain a connection to subscribe a topic and send some messages to it?

Comment: You need to provide more information about how you are using the ngx-mqtt plugin.

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages, they are very hard to read and impossible for people that need to use screen readers. You need to post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Comment: All of the updates have shared have the absolute bare minimum information making it very hard to actually help. At this point I suggest you delete this question and start again, include a proper [minimum viable testcase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) version of your code, rather than just the connection arguments because as it is we've had to guess to get this far, but really can't say anything more.

Comment: I edit the question with aditional informaction. I hope is enouph to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title bar in the image you initially posted it appears you started mosquitto with the following command:

```
mosquitto -p 1884 -v
```

This will start the mosquitto broker and ask it to set the port for the default listener to 1884. The default listener is always going to be native MQTT, if you want to connect with MQTT over WebSockets as is required from a web app (and can be seen from `protocol: 'ws'` in the code you posted, then you need to pass a proper configuration file to add a separate listener that is configured to accept MQTT over WebSockets.

If you create a file with the following

```
port 1883

listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

You can pass the config file to mosquitto with `-c`

```
mosquitto -c websockets.conf
```

Comment: @PedroSousa https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70022942/edit) the original question to add details rather than try and squash it into comments